# Smart dialog (Form) position without covering the control component and within screen ? (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, dialog

There is a DataGridView in my form. When I click a cell in this DataGridView, it would show a dialog.

```
Form_Para formPara = new Form_Para();
formPara.ShowDialog();
```

In general, I hope this dialog just **within screen** and below this cell.
If showing below this cell will out of screen, then change its position to above the cell.

I know I can get the size and position of dialog and range of screen to calculate new dialog position. However, is there a simpler method?

For example, when I set 'StartPosition' of dialogs as 'CenterParent'.
It will show in the center of parent form and **within screen automatically**. I don't need to calculate the new position for avoiding out of screen.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I think setting 'StartPosition' of dialogs as 'CenterParent' is simpler.
And then change only the Location.Y for avoiding to cover current cell.

```
Point currCellPosTop, currCellBottom;
currCellPosTop = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, true).Location;
currCellPosTop = dataGridView1.PointToScreen(currCellPosTop);
currCellBottom = new Point(currCellPosTop.X, currCellPosTop.Y );
currCellBottom.Y += dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Size.Height;

Form_Para formPara = new Form_Para(currCellPosTop, currCellBottom);   
formPara.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;         
formPara.ShowDialog();
```

Dialog Form:

```
private Point _TriggerControlPosTop;
private Point _TriggerControlPosBottom;
public Form_Para(Point triggerControlPosTop, Point triggerControlPosBottom)
{
    _TriggerControlPosTop = triggerControlPosTop;
    _TriggerControlPosBottom = triggerControlPosBottom;
    InitializeComponent();            
}
```

And visible change event of dialog:

```
private void Form_Para_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, _TriggerControlPosBottom.Y);
    if (_TriggerControlPosBottom.Y + this.Height > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height)
    {
        this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, _TriggerControlPosTop.Y - this.Height);
    } 
}
```